# Cambiar orden columnas archivo excel generado por Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, excel, kotlin

necesito cambiar el orden de estas columnas de un archivo excel generadas por una aplicación kotlin

Necesito que el campo descripcion quede en la columna G:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paso el código:

```
 package com.awecode.thupraiisbnscanner.db.entity

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "barcodeData")
data class BarcodeData(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "codigo") var codigo: String,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "Descripción") var currency: String?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "precio") var price: String?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "fecha") var date: String,
                       @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB, name = "imagen") var image: ByteArray?)
```

Comment: Si las respuestas a tu pregunta sirve, márcalas como correctas. En caso contrario, deja un comentario para que la persona que intentó ayudarte sepa que no has podido solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Parece sencillo. Solo debes cambiar el orden de las declaraciones, poniendo en último lugar `@ColumInfo(name = "Descripción"`

Te quedará así:

```
 package com.awecode.thupraiisbnscanner.db.entity

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "barcodeData")
data class BarcodeData(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "codigo") var codigo: String,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "precio") var price: String?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "fecha") var date: String,
                       @ColumnInfo(typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.BLOB, name = "imagen") var image: ByteArray?,
                       @ColumnInfo(name = "Descripción") var currency: String?)
```

Comment: Jose no me funciono me dio este error e: C:\Users\Matias\Desktop\ISBN-Scanner-master\app\src\main\java\com\awecode\thupraiisbnscanner\view\MainActivity.kt: (168, 17): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

Comment: Vaya, lo siento... ¿Y antes iba bien?... Veo que en la imagen que colocaste, en la columna fecha pone la imagen, y en la columna imagen pone la fecha...

De todos modos, prueba a quitar el interrogante al final de 'String'.

Mientras, reviso mis notas a ver si veo algo más...

Comment: Por lo que he visto, estás poniendo varias preguntas referentes al mismo código, y creo que lo estás cambiando sin saber mucho lo que haces. Y además, alguna pregunta que ya te han respondido y que te ha funcionado, no la has marcado como aceptada. Por mi parte, no me tomo más molestias hasta que muestres algo más de código, y cortesía con otros usuarios.